# Creating a display code for an ATM

Tags: vb.net

This code wrote enables these declarations to go into the ListBox but unfortunately when it's run, it just displays ONLY the account number and nothing else. I'm trying to find out what I did wrong but can't figure it out.

```
Dim Loan As Decimal
Dim Account_Number, CustomerName, OpeningBalance, CurrentBalance, Loan_Taken, Amount_of_Loan, Amount_Deposited As String

If OneAccount.LoanTaken Then
    Loan = OneAccount.CustomerLoan

    Account_Number = TextBox1.Text
    CustomerName = TextBox2.Text
    OpeningBalance = Val(TextBox3.Text)
    CurrentBalance = Val(TextBox3.Text) - Val(TextBox5.Text)
    Label8.Text = CurrentBalance
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Loan_Taken = "Yes"
    Else
        Loan_Taken = "No"
    End If
    Amount_of_Loan = Format(Loan, "Currency")
    Amount_Deposited = Label8.Text
    Amount_Deposited = Amount_Deposited
    Amount_Deposited = Format(Amount_Deposited, "Currency")

    ListBox2.Items.Add(String.Format(Account_Number, CustomerName, OpeningBalance, CurrentBalance, Loan_Taken, Amount_of_Loan, Amount_Deposited))
End If
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
ListBox2.Items.Add(String.Format(Account_Number, CustomerName, OpeningBalance, CurrentBalance, Loan_Taken, Amount_of_Loan, Amount_Deposited))
```

Here is the documentation for String.Format: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

I'm not sure exactly how you are trying to format it but, you could simply do

```
ListBox2.Items.Add(Account_Number + " " + CustomerName + " " + OpeningBalance + " " + CurrentBalance + " " + Loan_Taken + " " + Amount_of_Loan + " " + Amount_Deposited)
```

Which will add all the items into the listbox with a space in between.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line where you add the item into ListBox2. Change the String.Format to String.Join like this:

```
String.Join(" ", Account_Number, CustomerName, OpeningBalance, CurrentBalance, Loan_Taken, Amount_of_Loan, Amount_Deposited)
```

This will join all your values together with a space in between.

String.Format() doesn't work because it will take a String as the first argument and all following arguments will be inserted into the first string like this:

```
String.Format("Name: {0}, Age: {1}", "John", 20)
' "Name: John, Age: 20"
```

So it's either String.Concat() or String.Join().

```
String.Concat("Hello", "World", "!) ' "HelloWorld!"
String.Join(", ", "0", "1", "2", "3") ' "0, 1, 2, 3"
```